# Empty in-text reference using apacite with LaTeX and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apacite

I am relatively new to Latex, I hope I am able to explain the problem well enough. I am using overleaf and would like to use `apa` referencing style. I loaded `apacite` and specified it as bibliography. Also, I have the `apacite.bst` file in my director and in my `.bib` file a required references are included. When I compile my text I get a complete and accurate looking reference list. However, in-text in get empty brackets with only containing a separating comma.

I cannot find a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help!

my text looks like this before compiling:

```
\section*{Introduction} 
We rarely make decisions in social isolation and many decisions we make occur in a social context \cite{mannes2012social, sniezek1995cueing}. Especially in current day and age, with the ever increasing use of social media to share and propagate information, decisions are continuously shaped by our (virtual) social surroundings. While taking advice from others can be a beneficial strategy to increase accuracy in one’s judgments \cite{davis-stober2014,surowiecki2005wisdom}, the benefits of advice taking strongly depend on what and how advice is incorporated \cite{mahmoodi2015equality,toyokawa2019}.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how the load the `apacite` package. Please tell us if you load any other citation management packages.

Comment: i loaded `apacite` with `\usepackage{apacite}`; i did not use any other citation packages. at the end of my document i then used `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and `\bibliography{refs.bib}`

Comment: And, after running LaTeX on your document, did you then run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs? Please advise. Oh, and if the raw bib entries are contained in a file called `refs.bib`, the appropriate command is `\bibliography{refs}` -- *without* the filename extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide a small code you should be able to compile. Uses `biblatex` and `biber`. I will compile several times if your system is configured to do so, or do it manually. Check the `biber` log `.blg` that everything is OK.

Then compare with your setup and see if something is missing.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
style=apa,
]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname34.bib}   
@article{Carlson2011, 
author = {Carlson, Nicholas},
booktitle = {Businessinsider.com},
title = {{How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY Have?}},
note = {Available online at  \url{www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3}},
year = {2011},
}   

@book{companion94,
author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
title        = {The \LaTeX\ {Companion}},
year         = {1994},
edition      = 1,
publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
location     = {Reading, Mass.},
pagetotal    = 528,
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname34.bib}

\begin{document}    
    
\section*{Introduction} 
We rarely make decisions in social isolation and many decisions we make occur in a social context \citep{Carlson2011, companion94}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: out2]

Comment: thank you! this seems to work :)

Comment: Sorry, but `author = {Frank Mittelbach, Michael Goossens},` is very wrong. It has to be `author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michael Goossens},`. Observe that in `author` and `editor` fields, the keyword `and` *must* be used to separate authors. Moreover, `title = {The \LaTeX Companion},` should be replaced with `title = {The \Latex\ {Companion}},`. Please fix both issues.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.